# Cannot connect to VNC through reverse ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vnc, reverse-tunnel

I am trying to set up a connection between my work machine (running Ubuntu 20) and my home machine (running Ubuntu 18) through a (G)cloud instance (running Ubuntu 20). Because of the strict firewall rules on my work machine the current approach is to establish a reverse ssh connection from work to gcloud instance (`ssh -R 7000:localhost:22 user@gcloud.instance.ip.address`), then ssh into the instance from my local machine and from there ssh back into my office machine (`ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@localhost -p 7000`).

This all works fine, but I would like to enable desktop sharing, so I started a tigervnc server (`vncserver`) on my work machine (on port :2), but when I try to connect to it from my local machine (through the gcloud instance -- `vncviewer localhost:2`) I `Can't open display:`.

my .vnc/config file on my work machine is

```
session=Ubuntu
geometry=1920x1080
dpi=96
localhost
```

This cloud instance is itself running a desktop environment which I can connect to at https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/, but even connecting to localhost:2 on Remmina or TigerVNC Viewer from there does not work, giving just a black screen.

How can I connect to a remote desktop through a cloud instance?

P.S. the cloud instance does not have to have a desktop environment, I just thought it might make it easier, but any way to establish a remote desktop connection between my work and local machine, going through a cloud instance, works for me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure why this was not working but switching to x11vnc instead of tigervnc seems to work now (also forwarding port 5900 instead of 5901 -- `ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@localhost -p 7000` -- and connecting to localhost:5900 on remmina)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.